# What's the Word Given Other Words?

Tags: word, wordplay

One word to sure make you think

> Nothing

This word will certainly be considered too

> Pentagon

I ate pizza as a part of my breakfast this morning, if that's important

> Clockwork

Pay careful attention

> Bumfuzzled

Here's the last word for you

> Praying

What is the word I am thinking of?

Hint:

> It is a five letter word

Additional Hint:

> It is part of a name, a pretty familiar name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word is

> **Nerdy**

and it is obtained by:

> Looking for homophones of numbers (or just numbers) in each line, and looking at that index in each word (or the index - 1, if you're a programmer :-) )

Specifically:

> **One** word... [**N**othing]
>  ...be considered **too** (*two*) [P**e**ntagon]
>  I **ate** (*eight*) pizza... [Clockwo**r**k]
>  Pay careful at**ten**tion [Bumfuzzle**d**]
>  ...word **for** (*four*) you [Pra**y**ing]

This fits the hints because:

> It is a *five-letter word* contained within the OP's name, which makes it rather familiar to them...and, hopefully, more familiar to the community as time goes on (welcome to the puzzling forum!)

Comment: Excellent, I was worried someone wouldn't get it!